# Unrecognized function or variable

Tags: function, matlab

I'm trying to run the beginning of a script that was sent to me:

```
function [ FList ] = ReadFileNames(DataFolder)
DirContents=dir(DataFolder);
FList=[];
```

DataFolder is the name of the folder in which all my data is held. When I click the Run button I receive:

```
ReadFileNames(DataFolder)
Unrecognized function or variable 'DataFolder'.
```

And I'm not sure why?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply click Run, it's the same as running the command

```
ReadFileNames();
```

Note there are no inputs here, but your code expects (and requires) the input `DataFolder`.

So you have to do one of two things

1. Click the drop-down by the Run button, edit the *type code to run* prompt and add your folder. Then you can continue to click the Run button to execute this again. Note that once you've edited the default Run command for a function, the Run button icon changes slightly to reflect it:

   [image: run button]
2. A more common, and arguably more clear, way to run your function would just be to call it from the Command Window by typing `ReadFileNames('your/folder/path/here');` (and hitting Enter to run).

   [image: command window]